"Read timed out" error downloading Gradle, SDK Components, etc
I am experiencing difficulties installing SDK tools and other components from the SDK Manager in Android Studio. Whenever I attempt to install tools such as the emulator, command-line-tools or different SDK components, I encounter errors. Additionally, I'm facing issues with downloading Gradle.
I recently downloaded Android Studio on the same computer, and initially, everything worked perfectly. However, I am now encountering various problems with Android Studio. Even during the installation process, I encounter errors when trying to install SDK components.
I have extensively searched for solutions on platforms such as YouTube, Stack Overflow, and other websites. I have tried multiple methods, including reinstalling Android Studio more than five times, experimenting with different versions, and checking my firewall settings. Despite these efforts, none of the solutions have resolved the issues.Gradle ErrorComponents Error During Installation, Same Error If Download From The SDK Manager
I've checked my firewall and tried installing components directly from the links, but Android Studio still doesn't recognize them. I've tried lots of solutions from the internet, but nothing's worked. Even though my internet is fine, I keep getting a "Read Timeout" error. But it's weird because Android Studio can still download and install plugins perfectly fine.
